# GridView is not updating on UI after changing the item source list

Tags: xamarin, gridview, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I am using a GridView with item source property which is the list of objects. Initially I assign the list of items on page appearing which is also appearing on UI. But when i perform some operation on button click and update the items in the list, it doesn't updates on UI, I need to go back and come again.

```
  <grial:GridView
        x:Name="ItemList"
        Padding="10"
        ColumnSpacing="10"
        RowSpacing="10"
        ColumnCount="{
            grial:OnOrientationInt 
                PortraitPhone=2,
                LandscapePhone=2,

                PortraitTablet=2,
                LandscapeTablet=2,

                PortraitDesktop=2,
                LandscapeDesktop=2
        }"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        ItemsSource="{ Binding Items ,Mode=TwoWay}"
        Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }">
            <grial:GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:RegisterItemGridV2 />
                </DataTemplate>
            </grial:GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </grial:GridView>
```

My View model

```
public class LoadDistinctItemsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private IList<Items> items;

        public IList<Items> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set
            {
                items = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        public void LoadData(string _loadId, int _mode = 0)
        {
            Items = App.dataManager.GetLoadDistinctItems(_loadId, _mode);
        }
 }
```

I am calling loadData which is updating everytime, the count in Items list is increasing but not updating on UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ObservableCollection** instead of **IList** . It works fine on my side .

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am using a tabbed page, does it matter ?

Comment: Share your sample and I will test it on my side .

Comment: Where should i share

Comment: You can upload it to github .And don't forget to remove your personal info like password and account ID .

Comment: I cannot share the whole project, can you come on chat so I can share the content page and view model

Comment: I am afraid I could not do this. You can create  a new sample ,which contains the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you are modifiyng the List every often, you should not use List.

If you use a List and add or remove items at runtime, your ListView /Grid will not reflect those changes. 
If you use an ObservableCollection, changes will be reflected

(also, remove the space in `{ Binding}`

Comment: I have tried ObservableCollection as well but no result